# Bind-attr "for" attribute in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, data-binding, handlebars.js

I'm trying to include a unique id for an  and  tag to get a custom checkbox. The `{{input}}` tag outputs it correctly but the `<label {{bind-attr for=binding}}` does not. I'm a frontend guy new to Ember so I'm sure this should be trivial.

```
<ul class="col-menu dropdown-menu">
  {{#each columns}}
    <li>
      {{input type="checkbox" checked=checked id=binding}} 
      <label {{bind-attr for=binding}}><span></span></label>
      <span>{{heading}}</span>
      {{columns}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Here is the output ...

```
<li>
  <input id="activityTotal" class="ember-view ember-checkbox" type="checkbox" checked="checked"> 
  <label data-bindattr-2689="2689">
    <span></span>
  </label>
  <span>
    <script id="metamorph-53-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
    Events
    <script id="metamorph-53-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
  </span>
  <script id="metamorph-54-start" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
  <script id="metamorph-54-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should wrap all this in a component.

You really should not be manually binding the id like this as ember uses it internally but I think it is acceptable in this case as I can't think of a better way but you need to maintain the uniqueness.

I would so something like this to ensure the id is unique and uses

```
  checkBoxId: Ember.computed(function(){
    return "checker-" + this.elementId;
  }),
```

Here is the component's javascript file that will be executed when the component is ran:

```
App.XCheckboxComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  setup: Ember.on('init', function() {
    this.on('change', this, this._updateElementValue);
  }),
  checkBoxId: Ember.computed(function(){
    return "checker-" + this.elementId;
  }),
  _updateElementValue: function() {
    this.sendAction();

    return this.set('checked', this.$('input').prop('checked'));
  }
});
```

Here is the component's template, I use `unbound` to bind the unique `checkBoxId` with the label's for:

```
<label for="{{unbound checkBoxId}}">
   {{label}}
  <input id="{{unbound checkBoxId}}" type="checkbox" {{bind-attr checked="checked"}}>
</label>
```

Here is how you might use it:

```
<ul>
  {{#each contact in model}}
    <li>{{x-checkbox label=contact.name enabled=contact.enabled}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

And here is a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fitale/34/edit) for ember 1.7.1 and [here](http://jsbin.com/rewedu/5/edit) is a working jsbin for ember 1.11.1.

Answer (score 1):

As of [version 1.11](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.11.0/templates/binding-element-attributes/), you don't need `bind-attr`. You should be able to bind the attribute like this:

```
<label for={{binding}}></label>
```

Comment: I'm running Ember 1.7.1. I'm getting this when I have `<label for={{binding}}><span></span></label>` ....  `<label for="<script" id="metamorph-52-start" type="text/x-placeholder"><script id="metamorph-52-end" type="text/x-placeholder"></script>&gt;<span></span></label>`

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. With 1.7.1, you'll need to use the `bind-attr` syntax, but I'm not sure why it isn't working (I'm new to Ember myself, still learning). My best guess would be that `binding` may be a reserved word in Ember?

Comment: No problem. Wish I could be of more help. Good luck.